# Reordering Product Information tabs in Magento admin panel

Tags: magento

I'm trying to change the ordering of the tabs in adding and editing products in the admin panel by editing **app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php**. However, I've come into a stump with the Associated Products tab. I'd like to move it before Meta Information but I can't seem to find where the said tab is being set. Can someone please guide me on how to move the Associated Products tab up? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In this xml : `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/catalog.xml` the Associated Products tab is added separately after all tabs only for configurable products :

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_configurable>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab"><name>configurable</name><block>adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_super_config</block></action>
        <action method="bindShadowTabs"><first>configurable</first><second>customer_options</second></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_configurable>
```

Thus, you could make some rearrangements in this xml.